# How to get banner ad unite ID from firebase database?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-realtime-database

Admobe code has been tested and it works fine, now we want to replace the ad unit number with Firebase

```
String getBannerAdUnitId() {
  if (Platform.isIOS) {
    return 'ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2934735716';

  } else if (Platform.isAndroid) {
    return 'ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111';
  }
  return null;
}
```

I use firebase_database packages

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';

final ref = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref();
final androidBannerID = ref.child("AdmobAds").child('banner_id_android').get();
final iosBannerID = ref.child("AdmobAds").child('banner_id').get();


String getBannerAdUnitId() {
  if (Platform.isIOS) {
    return '$iosBannerID';

  } else if (Platform.isAndroid) {
    return '$androidBannerID';
  }
  return null;
}
```

this is firebase Database

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use [Firebase Remote Config](https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config).

You should first get instance of FirebaseRemoteConfig in this way:

```
    final remoteConfig = FirebaseRemoteConfig.instance;
    await remoteConfig.setConfigSettings(RemoteConfigSettings(
        fetchTimeout: const Duration(minutes: 1),
        minimumFetchInterval: const Duration(hours: 1),
    ));
```

You can also set default values, but i would not recommend doing so, as if your purpose is to not keep ad-ids in client app, then you should not set defaults here. But if you want to, you can set those in this way:

```
    await remoteConfig.setDefaults(const {
        "foo": 10,
        "bar": 20.225,
        "foo_bar": true,
        "bar_foo": "Sample String",
    });
```

You can fetch these values in this way:
`await remoteConfig.fetchAndActivate();`

For more details, view [Firebase Remote Config](https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/get-started?platform=flutter)

NOTE: I have not tried using FRC (Firebase Remote Config) in this way, but I hope it helps you in this way.